# Transition between main activity from Android studio after react native loads

Tags: android, reactjs, animation, react-native, transition

I have created a splash screen in Android Studio which appears before my react native application has loaded. [This is the guide I followed](https://medium.com/react-native-development/change-splash-screen-in-react-native-android-app-74e6622d699).

The actual splash screen works fine, but the problem is that when the app has loaded and it switches from the splash screen to the actual react native application, there is barely a transition between the two screens (on cold launch). They change very fast and abrupt.

Has anyone else experiences this, and is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually the correct way (best practice) of showing a splash screen. No need to make the user wait unnecessarily. But still, if you want to show the splash screen for few seconds then,

**Method 1**

You can create a new Activity and put a timeout there and then start your main activity. You can follow [this post](https://medium.com/handlebar-labs/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-a-react-native-app-ios-and-android-30a3cec835ae). But this also will not wait on the splash screen. To make it wait, add a timeout in your splash Activity (from the post I have linked) before starting MainActivity as follows:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }, 1000);

    }
}
```

here 1000 is time in milliseconds.

When you will run this in the android emulator you may run into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44209189/run-android-gives-error-when-connected-to-a-device/44221580#44221580). You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44221580/4575744) answer for the solution.

**Method 2**

You can create a full screen modal and show it on the main screen till the content of the main screen is loaded. I feel this solution better because this will cause the user to wait till something meaningful is happening. But, If content loading takes time then better to show something meaningful (not splash screen but content from the app), then load content in the background and then update the screen.

Comment: is this really best practice ?